# Classes not getting published to embedded tomcat server of maven (tomcat:run)

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-tomcat-plugin

I'm using eclipse indigo IDE, apache tomcat 6.0 server, m2e plugin,jdk 1.6 softwares in my project.

After i make some changes in java code i do clean & maven build and the start the tomcat embedded server using maven i.e. 'tomcat:run' plugin command. But after following all steps i don't see my changes reflecting at all.

Now after i build all classes i see that all the class files are generated inside 'target' folder which i confirmed with the time at which it was generated.So i believe these class files are not getting published to embedded tomcat server of maven for some reasons.

P.S - I don't start/stop or use tomcat server configured in eclipse as i believe embedded tomcat server of maven doesn't use tomcat server in eclipse and it works by itself.Please correct me if i'm wrong here.

Please help me out.

[Update]:
Might be useful for someone who is facing similar issue.

The above problem was because of eclipse project settings file getting corrupted as i was encountering the same problem when i imported the same projects in different workspaces.But when i included modified codes alone in new workspace,it worked fine. All my changes were getting reflected.

Answer (score 0):

use tomcat7:run 
Then configure backgroundProcessorDelay see http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.1/tomcat7-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html#backgroundProcessorDelay with > 0